# looping within list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list

By help [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754414/handling-json-data-using-jquery-sent-by-using-newtonsoft-json) got solved but still stuck..

[After trying this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524920/looping-through-json-array-in-a-jquery-list) I got an error on console log..

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [ { "id": 1, "name": "Bhavik", "phone": 9601109585 }, { "id": 2, "name": "Xyz", "phone": 1234567890 }, { "id": 3, "name": "Abc", "phone": 9876543210 } ]
[Break On This Error]   

throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
```

**jQuery code:**

```
var list = { "Persons": data.d };
$(list.Persons).each(function (index) 
{
     alert( this.id + "\n" + this.name + "\n" + this.phone);
});
```

**JSON array:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bhavik",
    "phone": 9601109585
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Xyz",
    "phone": 1234567890
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Abc",
    "phone": 9876543210
  }
]
```

I want to loop through the list.. Any ideas..

**EDIT** After @Vucko's suggestion I tried replacing `data.d` by the the JSON array itself and to my surprise it worked [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uR7m4/1/).. Any reason and solution for it..

**Solved** changed `var list = { "Persons": $.parseJSON(data.d)};`.. JSON response is not enough I guess.. We need to parse it also..

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/uR7m4/)?

Comment: @Vucko is there any mistake by me..?? your code works perfect..

Answer (score 1):

Your code has only one error :

```
var list = { "Persons": data.d };
                             ^
```

Change to :

```
var list = { "Persons": data };
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uR7m4/)

Comment: data.d gives me the JSON array.. I tried a small change replacing data.d with the array.. [Have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/uR7m4/1/). Also I tried `var list = { "Persons": data };` as you recommend but the alert gives undefined..

Comment: Shure, all that matters is that works. It all depends on how you use the JSON array and then you modify the code appropriate to that. Check the other questions about looping through JSON array ( [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each) ).

Comment: @Bhavik var list = { "Persons": data.d };
$.each(list.Persons, function (index) {
     alert( index.id + "\n" + index.name + "\n" + index.phone);
});